# Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, windows-console

In my program, I have to take 7 names and display them in alphabetical order. But I get the error

> Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int size = 7;
    
    int[] people = new int[size];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter " + i+1 + ". person's name: ");
    
        // Here
        people[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("After alphabetic ordering: ");
    
    Array.Sort(people);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j + 1 + "person's name : " + people[j]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Think about this: you are trying to store people name's which are strings into an array of integers.

Comment: Change From : int[] people = new int[size];  To : string[] people = new string[size];

Answer (score 1):

ReadLine method returns a string. So this code try to assign a string value to the int variable people.
Rewrite the code like below.

```
String[] people = new String[size];
```

or

```
var people = new String[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

You sould define `string[]` Not `int[]` so Use string[]

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int size = 7;
    
    string[] people = new string[size];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter " + i+1 + ". person's name: ");
        
        // Here
        people[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("After alphabetic ordering: ");
    
    
    
    Array.Sort(people);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j + 1 + "person's name : " + people[j]);
    }

    // ...
}
```